# How can I combine two (or more) preg_replace's - PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, bbcode

< EDIT >

I Wanted to give a big thank you to all of you who have provided an answer, You have all given me great options.  I will play with each and see which one suits my exact needs prior to selecting an answer.  I do appreciate all of your responses though, everyone has a different approach to things.  =)

bbcodes can (but not always do) include options, an example would be:

```
[URL="http://google.com"]GOOGLE[/URL]
```

</ EDIT >

I am currently hiding multiple variables from my string using the following method:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\[img\](.*)\[\/img\]/im', 'REPLACED', $qry);
$result = preg_replace('/\[url.*\](.*)\[\/url\]/im', 'REPLACED', $qry);
```

This works, but I would like to be able to do this with just one preg replace, and easily be able to add to it in the future if needed.

I have attempted to use:

```
$result = preg_replace("#\[/?(img|url)(=\s*\"?.*?\"?\s*)?]#im", 'REPLACED', $qry);
```

Which is only hiding the tags themselves.

How can I combine these replaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
preg_replace('~\[(img|url)\b[^]]*](.*?)\[/\1]~is', 'REPLACED', $qry);
```

The regex matches:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(img|url)` - Group 1: `img` or `url`
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[^]]*` -  0 or more chars other than `]`
- `]` - a `]` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `\[/\1]` - `[/`, the same contents as in Group 1, and a `]`.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/a8iWi):

```php
$qry = '[url="google.com"]google[/url] and [img]image here[/img]';
echo preg_replace('~\[(img|url)\b[^]]*](.*?)\[/\1]~is', 'REPLACED', $qry);
// => REPLACED and REPLACED
```

Comment: This one works for the way you described the qry, but bbcodes as I know them are more along the lines of `[url="http://blah.com"]` and this expression did not work for that, example: https://3v4l.org/scnXJ  I have added a bbcode example to the OP also.

Comment: You came in first, with a way that's easy to adapt for future use. https://3v4l.org/m0kU3  I apologize for not providing an example bbcode in the first place.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

preg_replace function can take array of arguments. As an option, you could try with:

```
$find = ['/\[img\](.*)\[\/img\]/im', '/\[url.*\](.*)\[\/url\]/im'];
$replace = ['REPLACED', 'REPLACED'];

$result = preg_replace($find, $replace, $qry);
```

I think this way you will have some flexibility to have different `replaced` values

Comment: This solution works well although I was looking for something more along the lines of `img|url` that way `img|url|its|easy|to|add|tags|to`

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is very close but you need to use a back reference to first capture group for closing match.

```
$result = preg_replace('~\[(img|url)\](.*)\[/\1\]~i', 'REPLACED', $qry);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/Ybvh2

The `m` modifier also has no functionality without an `^` or `$`. Perhaps you want the `s` modifier so the `.` extends to newlines? https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

I also would change the `*` quantifier to be non-greedy:

```
$result = preg_replace('~\[(img|url)\](.*?)\[/\1\]~is', 'REPLACED', $qry);
```

consider https://3v4l.org/8SdNd vs. https://3v4l.org/MC0pf (non greedied).

If you need to distinguish between images and URLs it is probably easiest to have 2 regexs. Functionality with 1 regex though can be achieved with `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('~\[(img|url)\](.*?)\[/\1\]~is', function($match){
        return $match[1] =='url' ? 'REPLACED url' : 'REPLACED img';
        }, '[img]test[/img][not]img[/not][url]http][/url]');
echo $result;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reference's and help, although I failed to provide an example of a bbcode thus messing up your answer.  bbcodes can contain options like `[url="http://google.com"]` I have updated this in the OP also. https://3v4l.org/scnXJ